# Handling Errors when Firebase Auth in different file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase's Web SDK in my Expo project, Redux is included too.

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a Promise; I used `.then()` to handle the Promise and `.catch()` for any errors. This action is done in a separate file, not in the Login Screen because I dispatch an action in the `then()` clause.

Question is how would I be able to catch the error at the client's side? I can't seem to find any scenario that is similar to mine.

It's a school project :') Appreciate any help please!

LoginScreen:

I have tried calling the Toast from a `useEffect` and in the `catch (error) { ... }` clause too but to no avail. I know this way would not work but I cant seem to find any solution online.

```js
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = React.useState(false);
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = React.useState('');
  const [alertStatus, setAlertStatus] = React.useState('');
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      // setAlertMessage(error);
      // setShowAlert(true);
      // setAlertStatus('danger');

      Alert.alert('Error Occured', error, [{ text: 'Close' }]);
    }
  }, [error]);

  const logInHandler = async () => {
    try {
      if (email.length === 0 || password.length === 0) {
        setAlertMessage('You have empty fields!');
        setShowAlert(true);
        setAlertStatus('warning');
        return;
      }

      dispatch(authActions.logIn(email, password));

      setError(null);
      setLoading(true);
      setAlertMessage('Logging In...');
      setShowAlert(true);
      setAlertStatus('info');
    } catch (err) {
      // setAlertMessage(err.message);
      // setShowAlert(true);
      // setAlertStatus('danger');
      setError(err.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return ( // i still don't get how to format properly when i paste codes here, sorry
        {showAlert && ( 
          <Toast  // this is a custom toast in a separate component that i made that only shows when there is an error
            message={alertMessage}
            status={alertStatus}
            hide={show => setShowAlert(show)}
          />
        )}     
  );
```

File containing the firebase auth methods:

Throwing the error causes an Exception, but what i'm trying to achieve is to get the error message and display it using the custom Toast if there is an error from firebase

```js
export const signUp = (email, password, name, gender) => dispatch => {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim().toLowerCase(), password)
    .then(res => {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName: name })
        .then(() => {
          dispatch({
            type: STORE_USER_DATA,
            id: res.user.uid,
            user: res.user.displayName
          });
          dispatch({
            type: SET_REGISTER,
            isRegistering: true,
            gender: gender
          });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('err.message', err.message));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      let message = 'actions.signUp: An error has occured!';
      let hasError =
        err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use' ||
        err.code === 'auth/invalid-email' ||
        err.code === 'auth/weak-password';

      if (hasError) {
        message = 'Invalid Credentials!';
      }

      throw new Error(message);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to dispatch the error instead of throwing the error - because the main usage of redux is state management so rather than throwing the error it makes more sense that you have a state that indicates if the login has failed or succeeded.

However i think it might be worth it to look at [react-redux-firebase](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/getting_started.html) package its a clean integration between firebase and react/redux application - you could checkout [authReducers, and authErrorReducers](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/reducers.html#authreducer) i think they might be helpful